# Factor table algorithm with complexity O(n·sqrt(n))

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

The following code prints a table of the factors of each number from 0 to *n*. Can someone help me rewrite the following O(n²) time code so that it has complexity O(n·sqrt(n)) time ?

I actually rewrote the algorithm to have O(n·log n) but I can't figure it out for that complexity.

```
public static Vector<Vector<Integer>> factTable(int n) {
  Vector<Vector<Integer>> table = new Vector<Vector<Integer>>();
  for (int i = 1;i <= n; i++) {
    Vector<Integer> factors  =  new  Vector<Integer>();
    for  (int  f  =  1;  f  <=  i;  f++) {
      if  ((i  %  f)  ==  0)  
      factors.add(f);
    }
  table.add(factors);
  }
  return  table;
}
```

Comment: IIRC, if f(x) is O(n log (n)) then f(x) is also O(n^1.5).

Answer (score 1):

For each factor f of i, i/f is a factor of i.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't proven the complexity but it is better than  O(n²).

```
int count = 0;
Vector<Vector<Integer>> table = new Vector<Vector<Integer>>();
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    table.add(new Vector<Integer>());
}
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j <= n; j += i) {
        Vector<Integer> vj = table.get(j);
        vj.add(i);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the O(n·log n) I came up with.